# Heroku install bad jdk (8) version in logs but good one (11) in terminal, which results in invalid target release: 11

Tags: java, spring, git, maven, heroku

I know this question was treated a lot of time, but i followed each and every one of the answers i could find, i checked everything i could think about but Heroku send me mixed signals.

I have a maven multi-module app with spring-boot,

i have a system.properties file with

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

My whole project is under java 11, i have in my parent pom.xml :

```
<java.version>11</java.version>
<maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
```

I even have added the right mvn command in the Procfile, which is normally not necessary

```
mvnw spring-boot:run -f ./cycle-api/cycle-api-webservice/pom.xml
```

my java and javac -version are 11

and when i do :

```
git push heroku feature/heroku:master
```

i have the right output in the terminal :

```
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Java app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 11... done
remote: -----> Executing Maven
```

but when i go to my heroku repository, and click on "open app", i have an error, and if i go to the logs i have the classical

```
[ERROR] ... Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
```

and if i go to the very top of the log i have

```
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
-----> Executing Maven
```

**How is it possible that it shows me two different version of JDK on the same build ?**

I even cloned the heroku git repository to check if everything is properly pushed, and yes it is.
So i have absolutely no idea about what could cause this strange behaviour, so any help would be highly appreciated ! Thanks !

Comment: system.properties is in the application’s root directory?

Comment: What does `heroku run java -version` (when executed in your local app directory) say? Are you sure that you're pushing to the right Heroku app? Do you see your push in your dashboard under "Latest activity"?

Comment: @BeppeC i think so. My parent module is "cycle-api", it's where i have the parent pom, and the system.properties, but my main springBoot class is in the sub package "cycle-api/cycle-api-webservice". Is it ok ?

Comment: @Malax it says openjdk version "11.0.7"

Comment: I restarted from a fresh heroku repository, and now the build seems to work, but i have a ```code=H14 desc="No web processes running"``` maybe i should open another topic about that

Comment: Does your procfile start with `web:`?

Comment: I finally found the solution, i will post the answer ! Thanks a lot for the help to you and @Malax too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally manage to deploy it.
So there was a problem with the git repo i think the remote was badly set. So i created a new heroku repo and i re-deployed from scratch. 
Then the Procfile doesn't allow the mvn command anymore apparently, so after that i had a mvn command not found error in the build. So finally i added to the Procfile :

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar ./cycle-api-webservice/target/cycle-api-webservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and now it's working. The app was crashing after deployment if i didn't add the

```
-Dserver.port=$PORT
```

and now everything is ok !